# Why a device is not detected on pci network card?

Tags: networking, ip, snmp, network-discovery

**UPDATE 1**

The OS on the server is `Windows 10 Enterprise`

I have a device that is connected directly to a server with an ethernet cable. No other ethernet cables or devices are connected to the server. The server has 2 built-in network ports and 2 ports from installed pci network card.
I set static ip `168.254.1.10/255.255.255.0` to the server's built-in port and `168.254.1.12/255.255.255.0` to the pci network card. The device has a utility software that detects the devices and once I click on one of the detected devices it opens a web brower ui and I can control the device (i.e. power cycle it).

When I connect the device to `168.254.1.10` built-in port, the device is detected. See image below:
[image]

But, when it's connected to the port on pci network card, it's not detected. See image below:
[image]

My question is, what could be the reason it's not detected in the second case?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, the fix is not applicable on the OS that's installed on the server. I've updated my post. I've also tried your second suggestion, but it didn't help.

Comment: What is the device that connects to the Ethernet? Can you disclose the make and model info of it?

Comment: This is the link to the device https://3gstore.com/product/7755_single_outlet_remote_power_switch_app_controlled.html

Comment: Maybe some type of duplex mismatch or something flaky like that when its NIC port talks with the card that has the 10 gbps speed. Have you already tried putting an inquiry in with support of the product to help troubleshoot? The ~Converged NIC is 10 GBE so you might mention that. Also you could try updating to latest drivers on the 10 GBE NIC if you can or also updating firmware on the IP outlet I suppose instructions at https://3gstore.com/site/support_portal_download.html?id=2677 on that process. Look this up on Amazon and read their reviews, it is there too in case you see a solution.

Comment: Can you reset this thing and connect it to a network that gives out DHCP addresses and then scan that subnet with AngryIP or some app and connect to it via it's DHCP assigned IP? I think this is the way it's supposed to work from what I read I think.

Comment: Did you determine anything with the DHCP IP address scan and such as I suggested?